# Duplicate error messages with validates_associated

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Here are two classes, 1:n relation

```rb
class Company < AR::Base
  has_many :brands
  validates_associated :brands
end

class Brand < AR::Base
  belongs_to :company
  validates_presence_of :name
end
```

I try to add brands for a company. If the brand name is empty, it gives me duplicated error messages.

```rb
c = Company.find(1)
c.valid?
# => true
c.brands.new
# => #<Brand id: nil, name: nil, company_id: 1, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
c.valid?
#=> false
c.errors.full_message
#=> ["Brands is invalid", "Brands is invalid"]
c.brands.last.errors.full_message
#=> ["Name required"]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Validates associated can be achieved by two ways
  First Option Simple:

```
has_many :brands, validate: true
```

Second Option is using validates_associated which will cause duplicate error message and can be avoided by explicitly setting validate to false:

```
has_many :brands, validate: false
validates_associated :brands
```

Note:
  You can go for second option if you need any additional options like validates_associated :if, :unless etc... otherwise go with first option which will not cause duplicate errors.

Comment: This helped me out a lot. Any idea why `validates_associated` created double errors unless you explicitly set it to false? If not, I'll go diving through the source when I have the time :P.

Comment: I actually figured it out while debugging! `validates_associated` will "assign" the associations errors to the parent object. Associations have `validate: true` by default so unless you change it to false, you'll get double errors. If you want the errors to be assigned to the associated object use `validates_associated` and explicitly set `validate: false` on the corresponding association. If you don't care or want them to remain on the associated object, leave `validates_associated` out and explicitly set `validate: true` if you like but you don't have to.

Answer (score 1):

A quick workaround to just remove duplicates from the array:

```
c.errors.full_messages.uniq
#=> ["Brands is invalid"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Here: 

c.errors.full_message
#=> ["Brands is invalid", "Brands is invalid"]
```

It's return two error message for each, because one for object of brands and  other for brand field validation error messaage. So, c.brands.last.errors.full_message is right way to validation.